# How to clone and add click event as separate element - without a closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

I am trying to clone a link form the document and append to `div` when I click on an add button.

Actually I am keeping a loop, in that loop each element need to calculate the number and need to add the class, but it's not working.

The number continuous from last element click.

The wrong output :

```
<div id="parent">    
  <a class="clicker Hi0 Hi1 Hi2" href="#">Click me</a> //it should Hi1,Hi2,Hi3
  <a class="clicker Hi0 Hi4 Hi5" href="#">Click me</a>//it should Hi1,Hi2,Hi3
  <a class="clicker Hi1 Hi2 Hi3" href="#">Click me</a>//it should Hi1,Hi2,Hi3
</div>
```

When i click first time i am getting one link appended but second time i am getting 3 buttons appended.

Here is my code:

```js
var multiClicker = function() {

  var clicker = $('.clicker').clone();
  var i = 0;
  clicker.click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('Hi' + i++);
  });

  clicker.appendTo('#parent');

}

$('button').click(function() {
  multiClicker();
})
```

```css
#parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 200px;
}
a.clicker {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parent">

</div>
<a class="clicker" href="#">Click me</a>

<div>
  <button>Make Clicker</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting multiple clickme links inserted is your selector is on the class which also gets cloned.

Here is the solution for the multiple click me links (changing the clone selector to an id)

```
var clicker = $('#clicker').clone();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7ooz6p9g/3/

Comment: The problem with this is that you should not be creating multiple elements with the same ``id`` in the same ``document``, this is bad practice. You also did not update the CSS in the example to reflect your change (e.g. ``a#clicker`` instead of ``a.clicker``). My solution uses the original CSS, and does not create a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line `$('.clicker').clone()`. Because you've added several of them to the DOM, you're cloning all of them rather than just the original. Also, if you want the class to start at `"Hi1"`, start with `i=1`. Try this:

```
var originalClicker = $('.clicker');

var multiClicker = function () {

    var clicker = originalClicker.clone();
    var i = 1;
    clicker.click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('Hi' + i++);
    });

    clicker.appendTo('#parent');
};

$('button').click(function(){
    multiClicker();
});
```

Or if you want even better code, you can simplify that to this:

```
var originalClicker = $('.clicker');

$('button').click(function () {

    var clicker = originalClicker.clone();
    var i = 1;
    clicker.click(function() {
        $(this).addClass('Hi'+i++);
    });

    clicker.appendTo('#parent');

});
```

Here's the updated link with your demo: http://jsfiddle.net/7ooz6p9g/4/